# Alternatives for replacing text selection under Outlook with custom HTML code

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, outlook-addin

I need to replace an user selection while editing an Outlook e-mail with my custom HTML code.

I tried two approaches:

#### Using the Clipboard

1. In HTML mode.
2. Getting the `Word.Range` from the `Word.Selection`.
3. Doing a `range.Copy()` to put it in the clipboard
4. Convert `inputString` to `outputString`
5. Replacing the selection with `outputString` with `range.PasteSpecial(...)`

#### Using the Open XML Format

1. In HTML mode.
2. Getting the `Word.Range` from the `Word.Selection`.
3. Doing a `range.Copy()` to put it in the clipboard.
4. Convert `inputString` to `outputString` (in Office Open XML format, knowing how to craft it to produce a specific HTML).
5. Replacing the selection with `outputString` with `range.InsertXML(...)`

The issues are:

1. When using the clipboard it crashes sometimes. There are references about checking the clipboard state but I think I've tried the known alternatives.
2. To use the `insertXML` you need to have Microsoft Word installed. You can't do an `insertXML` with Outlook installed alone. Look at: [Impact of deploying Outlook 2007 without Word 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179031%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for further information.

Do you know more alternatives? I can think of adding the elements myself like using `InsertParagraph`, but I am not sure if I can add hyperlinks or will experience similar issues.

Comment: I'm confused re the scope of the queston. What is `Word.Range` or do you just mean selecting part of your outlook email for formatting? Can you show your current VBA to help us progress this?

Comment: My guess is that the clipboard crashes because of the the delays, have you tried inserting a Sleep command in between the copy & paste ?

Answer (score 1):

According to msdn, the HTMLEditor has been [deprecated in Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176908%28v=office.12%29.aspx) - see the fourth section down, "HTML Editor".

Technically, you can still access the HTML through `MailItem.HTMLBody`, but it's just a read/write string value so you wouldn't be able to find out what portion of the text is highlighted directly.

Using `MailItem.getInspector.WordEditor`, you could find out what specific text is highlighted and then find and replace it in the HTMLBody via vba's `Replace`, surrounded by your html.

Considering how convoluted that is, you may want to use `WordEditor` to make your formatting changes directly.  I didn't see anything in the link you provided that would indicate the `WordEditor` object isn't available in a standalone Outlook 2007 installation, but I have the full office suite so I can't test it myself. [this site](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=31) describes how to do it with the `WordEditor`.